# AsyncTask in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

I can not understand how to translate a simple AsyncTask in RxJava.  Take for example:

```
private class Sync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
              String proxy_arr = "";
                    try {
                        Document jsoup_proxy = Jsoup.connect(Constants.SITE_PROXY_LIST)
                                .userAgent(Constants.USER_AGENT)
                                .ignoreContentType(true)
                                .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                                .timeout(Constants.USER_TIMEOUT)
                                .get();

                        if (jsoup_proxy != null) proxy_arr = jsoup_proxy.text().trim();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        new DebugLog(getActivity(), "News", "Sync PROXY", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }
              return proxy_arr;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result.equals("err_internet")){
            func.toastMessage(R.string.toast_err_nointernet, "", "alert");
        }

        reloadAdapter();
    }
}
```

As it can be translated in the same working condition RxJava?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `Observable.create` you should use either `Observable.defer()` or better yet `Observable.fromCallable` (which was introduced in RxJava 1.0.15) - because these methods will ensure a proper observable contract and save you from some mistakes you can introduce when creating observable by hand.

Also instead of going with `runOnUiThread` as suggested in one of the answers above, you should really use `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` which was created for exactly this purpose. Just use [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) library which provides it.

I suggest the following solution:

```
public Observable<String> getJsoupProxy() {
  return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
      try {
        Document jsoup_proxy = Jsoup.connect(Constants.SITE_PROXY_LIST)
          .userAgent(Constants.USER_AGENT)
          .ignoreContentType(true)
          .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
          .timeout(Constants.USER_TIMEOUT)
          .get();

        return jsoup_proxy != null ? jsoup_proxy.text().trim() : "";
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // just rethrow as RuntimeException to be caught in subscriber's onError
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    });
}

getJsoupProxy()
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // this scheduler is exported by RxAndroid library
  .subscribe(
     proxy -> {
       if(proxy.equals("err_internet")) {
         // toast
       }
       reloadAdapter();
     },
     error -> new DebugLog(getActivity(), "News", "Sync PROXY", Log.getStackTraceString(error)));
```

Comment: As a side note, from my experience using Jsoup in android is really heavy. That library is not optimized for Android usecase and creates *a lot* small and short lived object which result in a lot of GC work. Although I'm not sure if good alternative exists...

Answer (score 3):

When you convert a functionality to be reactive please keep in mind that you should define

- onNext
- onError
- onCompleted

"events".

Actually rx is working well with data sequences, but of course you can create a data sequence with only one emitted item. 
So to modify your method to be reactive I'd say first you should decouple the responsibilities.

Somewhere in a repository class or you name it according to your architecture you just create this:

```
    public Observable<String> getProxyAsync() {
        return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            String proxy_arr = "";
            try {
                Document jsoup_proxy = Jsoup.connect(Constants.SITE_PROXY_LIST)
                    .userAgent(Constants.USER_AGENT)
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                    .timeout(Constants.USER_TIMEOUT)
                    .get();

                if (jsoup_proxy != null) proxy_arr = jsoup_proxy.text().trim();

                subscriber.onNext(proxy_arr);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            } finally {
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        });
    }
```

after that, somewhere near to the activity, just subscribe to this method like this:

```
public void myPreciousMethod() {
    myCustomRepo.getProxyAsync()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe(result -> {
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                if (result.equals("err_internet")) {
                    func.toastMessage(R.string.toast_err_nointernet, "", "alert");
                }
            });
        }, throwable -> {
            // some exception happened emmited by your code, handle it well
            new DebugLog(getActivity(), "News", "Sync PROXY", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }, () -> {
            // onCompleted:
            runOnUiThread(() -> reloadAdapter());
        });
}
```

I would suggest to use `.runOnUiThread()` (in your activity or any other view related operation with rx) to avoid backpressure, but it really depends on the amount and frequency of emitted data. (you can use `.observeOn()` and `.subscribeOn()` as well) Plus using the retrolambda is highly recommended too in sake of much more cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it. You could forego the defer if need be.

```
        Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<String> call() {
                    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                            String proxy_arr = "";
                            try {
                                Document jsoup_proxy = Jsoup.connect(Constants.SITE_PROXY_LIST)
                                        .userAgent(Constants.USER_AGENT)
                                        .ignoreContentType(true)
                                        .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                                        .timeout(Constants.USER_TIMEOUT)
                                        .get();

                                if (jsoup_proxy != null) proxy_arr = jsoup_proxy.text().trim();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                new DebugLog(getActivity(), "News", "Sync PROXY", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                            }
                            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                                subscriber.onNext(proxy_arr);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                @Override
                public void call(String result) {
                    if (result.equals("err_internet")){
                        func.toastMessage(R.string.toast_err_nointernet, "", "alert");
                    }
                    reloadAdapter();
                }
            });
```